SeleniumBase won't bypass a Cloudflare CAPTCHA in headless mode
I attempted to scrape a website that has a bot-blocker from cloudflare using this code:
with SB(uc=True, headless2=True) as sb:
    for url in urls:
        sb.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 5)
        sb.uc_gui_handle_captcha()

There was an error:
Exception: PyAutoGUI can't be used in headless mode!

How can I pass the CAPTCHA in headless mode without PyAutoGUI? Or is there an alternative way to solve this problem?

I have tried many approaches, like using cookies, virtual display etc., and nothing worked.

Could you please share full error trace with. Now its unclear which line raises an error

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 20
18 for url in urls:
19     sb.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 5)
---> 20     sb.uc_gui_click_captcha()
22     has_next_page = True
24     while has_next_page:
exception: PyAutoGUI can't be used in headless mode!

Use the SeleniumBase Xvfb virtual display to simulate headless mode in a headless environment on Linux:
For your script, the solution would look something like this:
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, xvfb=True) as sb:
    urls = [URL1, URL2]
    for url in urls:
        sb.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 5)
        sb.uc_gui_click_captcha()
        # Do more stuff here

(Note that Xvfb is for Linux environments. Don't use headless mode with UC Mode.)
